# How can we perform transaction integrity in edm

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am using edmx(Ado.net Entity Data Model) fro one of my project .
I want to manage my save transactiion.
I want to perform transaction integrity for all the transaction .
How can I perform this.
Can someone provide me some tutorial

Comment: *I want to perform transaction integrity for all the transaction* what does this mean? EF runs transaction every time you call `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka read my exact query in comment of the below answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SaveChanges` will create it's own transaction. The changes in the `ObjectContext` will only be accepted when the transaction completes successfully.

If you want more control over your transaction (maybe for multiple actions against different ObjectContexts) you can use your own `TransactionScope` and the Entity Framework will detect this transaction and use it for his own operations.

[Here is the MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx) about managing transactions.

Comment: my situation is this - suppose i want to save data in Image table which generate imageID , then I want to save data in page table with that image ID  which generate pageID,and now i want to add both pageID and ImageID in third table PageImage ,so I want if any one transaction fails then all the transaction will get roll back
that what I want

Comment: That will be all done automatically if you have correctly defined model with navigation properties and you save both image and page with same call to `SaveChanges`.

Comment: If all those objects belong to the same ObjectContext Entity Framework will make sure that all Ids are set correctly. You only have to associate the objects with eachother, nothing special. If they are part of different ObjectContexts you will need to span them with your own transaction. Why don't you show us some code?